# iOS 6 Objective-C Post Splash Screen in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to display a splash screen for some small amount of time longer than the default splash screen. One way to do it is to put an image view up in App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWitOptions method. I am putting an image view up as shown below, and for now I never take it down because I want to make sure it works.

I never see the image view! The UIImage is created ( the file exists ) and the size printed is correct..

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not showing up? Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Put an image view splash screen up for a little while for loading purposes
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
    NSLog(@"image size is %f %f",image.size.height,image.size.width);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = self.window.bounds;
    //imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    imageView.hidden = NO;
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to attach your `UIView` to a `UIViewController` and set this view controller as the window root view controller:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[vc.view addSubview:imageView]
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[self.window addSubview:vc.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Since you are calling `self.window.rootViewController = vc;`, it is inappropriate to also call `[self.window addSubview:vc.view];`. The latter was made deprecated by the former.